# How can we replace HttpConnection Connector.open(URL) using in J2ME into android

Tags: android

We have HttpConnection Connector.open(URL) in J2ME how can we replace this class when using it in android?

Comment: use this: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.htmland http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpConnection.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `HttpUrlConnection` in android.

Example:

```
URL url = new URL("http://google.com");
HttpUrlConnection conn = (HttpUrlConnection)url.openConnection();
```